# Flutter http request issue

Tags: flutter, dart, http, flutter-http

I'm trying to check an url with the `http` package.

The code looks like this:

```
  Future<void> checkURl() async{
    final response =
        await http.get(
        Uri.parse('https://someurl.com'));
  }
```

The http package is imported, but somehow the IDE marks the 'http' invalid. This is the error message:

```
Error: The getter 'http' isn't defined for the class '_MyHomePageState'.
 - '_MyHomePageState' is from 'package:movies_app/screens/detail_screen.dart' ('lib/screens/detail_screen.dart'). Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'http'.
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://someurl'));
```

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the use case, you are using as prefix to import http, import like

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

To use like `await http.get`

Answer (score 2):

no need to do `http.get`, you can do

```
 import 'package:http/http.dart';

 Future<void> checkURl() async{
    final response =
        await get(Uri.parse('https://someurl.com'));
  }
```

if you want to do

```
await http.get(Uri.parse('https://someurl.com'));
```

then import the package as

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```